New FileStream is closed immediatly
I have a long running process handling imports. The imports went fine for a long time, but suddenly suddenly got an exception, even though I did not change anything. Importing the file uses the library NPOI.
One process copies the file to the folder:
System.IO.File.Copy(fileNameDownload, path);

Then a couple of minutes later another process tries to access it:
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
  var xlsxBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs); // suddenly threw exception
  var xlsBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

But accessing this filestream suddenly threw a new exception:
Cannot access a closed file
at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at NPOI.Util.IOUtils.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len) in C:\github\npoi\main\Util\IOUtils.cs:line 179
   at NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem.NPOIFSFileSystem..ctor(Stream stream) in C:\github\npoi\main\POIFS\FileSystem\NPOIFSFileSystem.cs:line 291

After restarting the service, the error disappeared. I would like to get to the bottom of it though, to avoid it in the future.

Are you sure you are not simply closing or disposing the file stream prematurely? Perhaps due to using some kind of threaded or asynchronous code? The example and call stack are incomplete, so it is not clear what the exact error is.

Also doing file access in a constructor is a big code-smell anyway.

@JonasH Yes, I am sure I am not disposing it. Also the error suddenly appeared and after restart has not appeared again. If I had disposed it, the error would stay.

@Charlieface It is a library, which uses the stream to create the object.

@JonasH That's all the call stack from the log I have.

Then you'd need to investigate/debug that library, we don't have enough info.

Are you sure XSSFWorkBook is not IDisposable? The library might be using threads internally, and require dispose/close or something else to synchronize. Reading the library documentation might also be a good idea.

@JonasH Yes, actually it is IDisposable, but we are not disposing it at all. So there's probably some kind of memory leak? Could this cause this error?
Also currently we use a method to return the workbook. Using a method wont work anymore with a using block. Any idea for a workaround to still be able to have this logic extracted in a method?

The exception looks to be from a background thread. My guess is that the workbooks uses a background thread for saving changes asynchronously, and some old object failed since the underlying stream has been disposed.
If the workbooks implement IDisposable they need to be disposed (unless the documentation specifies differently). Typically like
using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using var xlsxBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
using var xlsBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

If you are returning the workbooks you have a bit more to consder.
It is common for objects to require that any passed streams are alive for the lifetime of the object. Objects may also take ownership of the stream, making disposing of the file stream unnecessary and possibly counter productive. Often with a "leaveOpen"-flag to opt out. This should all be specified in the documentation.
If the documentation is unclear it is best to be conservative and dispose everything in the inverse order of creation. For example by using a wrapper:
public class MyWrapper(FileStream Fs, XSSFWorkbook XlsxBook, HSSFWorkbook XlsBook) : IDisposable{

    public void Dispose(){
         XlsBook.Dispose();
         XlsxBook.Dispose();
         Fs.Dispose();         
    }
}

Just ensure that the caller eventually disposes the returned object.
